# OLE DB provider for ADO.NET data source

Tags: ado.net, oledb

I have an application which can connect to OLE DB data sources, however, my proprietary database has only ADO.NET provider.

Is there any ADO.NET to OLE DB bridge which could helps me to connect to ADO.NET data source?

**EDIT:**

I do not have control on application. It is some kind of reporting service. Here is how I expect to connect:

App <-> OLE DB Provider <-> (bridge?) <-> ADO.NET Data Source

Everything is running on Windows machine

Comment: ADO.Net can talk to OLE just fine. The question is whether OLE can talk to ADO.Net.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the platform so I am going to assume things and point you to some direction.

> For the .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB, the connection string
>   format is identical to the connection string format used in ADO

For more details you can refer to this page to get started:

[Connecting to an OLE DB Data Source Using ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719763%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

And also it wouldn't hurt to have a look at this title **Connecting to an OLE DB Data Source**
in the following MSDN article (.NET 4.5)

[Establishing the Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254507%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Update**

On the other hand to access a ADO.NET data source using an OLE DB you can follow this example.

However if you mean by the word "bridge" to have something like

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(oleConnectionString))
```

where, `oleConnectionString` is an originally an OLE connection string which is converted to act as an SQL connection string?! I am not sure if that's possible.

[ADO.NET Sample](http://opensourcejavaphp.net/csharp/reportdotnet/AdoSample.vb.html)

Comment: I don't think that I can connect to ADO.NET Data source using OLE DB provider without something in between them. btw, data source is not MSSQL Server.

Comment: AFAIK, using Microsoft ADO.NET you can connect to these 4 types of providers: SqlClient, OleDb, Odbc and Oracel. I just can't get my head around working of Ado.Net provider or DataSource